# Can't build a new project with xcode on my MacPro

Tags: iphone, xcode, osx-snow-leopard, xcodebuild

I've installed on my MacPro (intel) Xcode 3.2.1 (iPhone SDK 3.1.2) and Snow Leopard

I made a new project (called Untitled) for iPhone OS, when I try to build, it returns an error:

```
*file not found: 
*/Users/user/Documents/Untitled/build/Untitled.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Untitled.build/Objects-normal/i386/main.o
*/Users/user/Documents/Untitled/build/Untitled.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Untitled.build/Objects-normal/i386/UntitledAppDelegate.o*

*Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1*
```

and doesn't go over!!

what i've to do to fix?

thank you for your answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Untitled" is a common place holder so it's possible that the using that as the project name has caused a problem with one of the build scripts. Try another project with a more unique name.

Other possible problems: (1) Permissions problem with the build directories (2) if you messed with the build settings you might have switched off the creation of the executable.

Edit01:

(Response to comment)

It sounds like you have a nasty corruption problem for some reason. Some things to try.

(1) Create a new user and try to run Xcode from that account. That will tell you if the problem is with the developer install or if its some kind of preferences or other file in the user's home directory. Xcode and the other dev apps dynamically create a lot of directories and files that an reinstall will not affect.

(2) You can do a complete uninstall of the developer tools from the command line.

`sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all`

(3) Xcode is just a face application for a full suit of unix command line development tools. If you installed different versions of these tool e.g. gcc, gdb etc, you might have altered something critical.

(4) Xcode plug-ins can cause problems. Make sure you remove all of them.

I had a crash in Xcode once, and afterwards I could never get Xcode to run under that user account. I spent nearly two days trying to troubleshoot before giving up and moving to another account. That turned out to be a good thing because it allowed me to create an account focused solely on development without all the distractions of my normal account.

Comment: i've tried also with many other project name but is the same problem... i will check the permission but consider that all the others files were created successfully. t works if i buld/execute a project created by another mac (xcode+leopard). I've never modified any kind of settings. I've also tryed to uninstall (reboot) and install again from a brand new disk image downloaded from apple.

Comment: I've make two different test:
1. make a complete uninstall via command line that doesn't solve the problem
2. create a new account and finally WORKS!!!

THANK YOU!

p.s.: I'd never installed any kind of xcode plug-in and/or tools (gcc, gdb, etc). so I guess I've encountered your same problem with accounts.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't Xcode 3.2 (not 3.1.2) ship with Snow Leopard? If you're using Snow Leopard, you should be using the appropriate version of Xcode for Snow Leopard, which is the 3.2 series.

Comment: thank you for the answer but i've write wrong version of xcode, i'll fix immediatly. I've installed Xcode ver 3.2.1.